# Cannot find .htaccess, can I create one? What else can I use to redirect html pages to blog posts

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website and want to redirect all its pages to posts on my blog. I browsed through my website folder but could not find the '.htaccess' file. Is it provided by the web hosting or can I create my own and use it? Can it be only used with Apache server.

If that's not possible what other option do I have for redirection.

Janice

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Since .htaccess is a hidden file, make sure, when you are browsing for this file, that you have the ability to see hidden files.  Like in you FTP client there will be an options to show hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

You create your own .htaccess, by simply opening a document and saving it as .htaccess.

You'll want something like this in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just don't see the .htacces file. The dot at the beginning of the file name indicates that this is a hidden file and will not be displayed normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess around with editing your .htaccess file, [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) is a good Wordpress plugin that handles 301 redirects, logs, etc. and is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is for Apache only, other web servers have their own methods of configuration and do not use .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged "Wordpress" maybe you are using that? Wordpress will create one after you've turn on pretty permalinks.